# Django form not sending data to admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form users can fill out to reserve a table at a restaurant. However when they submit the form no data gets sent to the admin side.

I have watched some tutorials and read other posts on this site and nothing seems to fix it. I feel like it is something so small but I just cant figure it out.

views.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic, View
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def Book(request):
    """
    Renders the book page
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("accounts/login")

    book_form = BookForm(data=request.POST)

    if book_form.is_valid():
        instance = book_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    else:
        book_form = BookForm()
    return render(
        request,
        "book.html",
        {
            "book_form": BookForm(),
        }
    )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number_of_guests = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    requests = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.date} for {self.name}"
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Book
from django import forms


class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = (
            'name',
            'number_of_guests',
            'date',
            'email',
            'requests',
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this view:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.shortcuts import redirect,render

@login_required(login_url="accounts/login")
def Book(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        book_form = BookForm(request.POST)

        if book_form.is_valid():
            book_form.save()
            return redirect("some_success_page")

        else:       
            return redirect("some_error_page")
    else:
        book_form = BookForm()
    return render(
        request,
        "book.html",
        {
            "book_form": book_form,
        }
    )
```

In settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL="accounts/login"
```

Comment: This was amazing, i found a solution but this looks much easier, and allows me to redirect users on different pages if they are successful or not. One of the main issues as to why the original code did not work was due to using a DateTimeField, so when i entered 2023 instead of 23, the data would not go through.